# How to align the text layouts from center of the screen to below in android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to build a layout like mentioned in below screenshot. I have full screen background image and want to display text from start from center of the device to below. text is dynamic text.

i tried with below code but not able to achieve exact layout

```
Scaffold() {
    Box() {
       Image() //full screen background 
    }
    Column(verticalArrangment = Arrangment.Center) {
      Text()
      Text()
      Text()
      Text()
      Text()
      Text()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put 2 composables with `weight(1f)` modifier into a `Column`. The bottom composable is a `Column` with the `Text` composables. The top composable here is `Spacer`, but can be replaced with something else if you need, just keep `weight` modifier with the same value.

```
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            Text("Title1")
            Text("Description")
            Text("Description")
        }
    }
```

[image]